# Problem with MIPS sorting code print array

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

Im having an issue with my sorting code. So the printFirstArray and second loop functions print out
the initial list before it sorts but when I do the printArray and finalLoop it doesn't output anything

im assuming thats because the previous functions set the addresses to the bottom of the stack so nothing outputs. If thats the case how do I reset it so that it points back to the top

```
.data
    vals: .space 4000
    message1: .asciiz "Enter an integer: 9999 to sort \n"
    message2: .asciiz "Sorted array: \n"
    message3: .asciiz "You have entered: \n"
    next_line: .asciiz "\n"

.text
    .globl main
    main:

        la $a1, vals # base address of the array
        li $a2, 9 # $a2 = 9;

        li $t0, 0 # i = 0;
        li $t1, 9999
    
    
    
    loop:
        #sends out first msg
        la $a0, message1
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        li $v0, 5
        syscall
        beq $v0,$t1,printFirstArray #begins sorting if 9999 is inputted
        addi $t0,$t0,4
        sw $v0, ($a1)
        addi $a1, $a1, 4 # moves array over by 1
        j loop 
        
    printFirstArray:
        la $a1,vals

        la $a0, message3
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
    
    secondLoop:
        #prints sequence
        blez $t0, sort
        li $v0, 1
        lw $a0, 0($a1)
        syscall
        la $a0, next_line
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        addi $a1, $a1, 4
        addi $t0, $t0, -4
        j secondLoop
    sort:

        la $t4, vals #t0 is number up to outter loop
        la $t1, vals #t1 is number comparing to inner loop
        addi $t1,$t1,4
        la $t8,vals
        add $t8,$t0,$t8
        la $t9,vals
        add $t9,$t0,$t9
        addi $t9,$t9,-4
    loopsec: 
        lw $t2,($t4) #gets number 1 of outter loop
        lw $t3,($t1) #gets number 2 of inner loop
        blt $t2,$t3,next #executes if a swap isnt necessarry
        sw $t3,($t4) #swap
        sw $t2,($t1)
    next: 
        addi $t1,$t1,4
        blt $t1,$t8,loopsec #checks if inner loop is done
        addi $t4,$t4,4 #if yes then increments the outer loop
        move $t1,$t4
        addi $t1,$t1,4
        blt $t4,$t9,loopsec #jumps to loops if outer loop is done

    printArray:
        la $a1,vals
        la $a0, message2
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
    finalLoop:
        #checks each line until t0 is less than or equal to 0
        blez $t0, done 
        li $v0, 1
        lw $a0, 0($a1)
        syscall
        la $a0, next_line
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        addi $a1, $a1, 4
        addi $t0, $t0, -4
        j finalLoop
    done:
        j done
```

Comment: This kind of this is best done in C first, tested in C so you know you have a working algorithm, and then translated to assembly, knowing there are no algorithmic problems.  Then your debugging is limited to assembly language translation errors not algorithm design problems.

Comment: What do you see when you single step in the debugger?  Find where it first goes wrong and deal with that.  Hint: how are you tracking the count of items?

Comment: There are no functions here, and no stack, so those terms (as per conventional usages) are not applicable.

Comment: well the count is being tracked by $t0 how can I set $t0 to point to the top of the array?

Comment: There's no magic.  You can set it to something you have previously saved or otherwise can compute.  If you simply count it down to zero, then it's gone.  Computers are good at remembering things when they're told to do so, and if not, then not so much.